# Mocking and HttpContextBase.get_User()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks

I want to mock the User property of an HttpContext.
I'm using Scott Hanselmans MVCHelper class and RhinoMocks.

I have a unit test that contains code, like this:

...

```
MockIdentity fakeId = new MockIdentity("TEST_USER", "Windows", true);
MockPrincipal fakeUser = new MockPrincipal(null, fakeId);

using (mocks.Record())
{
    Expect.Call(fakeHttpContext.User).Return(fakeUser);
}
```

...

My MockIdentity and MockPrincipal classes are mocks conforming to IIdentity and IPrincipal, respectively.

I get an error when running the unit test that reports:

> System.NotImplementedException : The
>   method or operation is not
>   implemented. at System.Web.HttpContextBase.get_User()

This is happening when I'm trying to set the expectation for the User property.

I understand that the httpContextBase has a getter and setter that aren't implemented but I thought that Rhino would handle this when mocking.

Does this mean that I have to derive from the HttpContextbase and override the property for my mock object. It seems odd.

Other users have had this issue and it's reported here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/rhinomocks@googlegroups.com/msg00546.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To mock the user property, you can do this:

```
var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
httpContext.Stub(x=>x.User).Return(yourFakePrincipalHere);

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, ....);

var controller = new HomeController();
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

(this uses the new RM 3.5 api, if you're doing it w/ record/replay then:

```
using(mocks.Record)
{
   _httpContext = _mocks.DynamicMock<HttpContextBase>();
   SetupResult.For(_httpContext.User).Return(...);
}

using(mocks.PlayBack())
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Brialliant Ben. Cheers. I think my understanding of Stubs and Mocks needs some 'brushing up'.

I did get an issue with:
httpContext.Stub(x=>x.User).Return(yourFakePrincipalHere);
but replaced with:
httpContext.User -= [fakeUser];
Which worked fine.

Answer (score 13):

I had nearly the same problem and moved to Moq.

This is the custom helper I uses in my apps:

```
public static class MvcMockHelpers
    {
        public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
        {

            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
            var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
            var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

            context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
            context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
            context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
            context.Expect(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);


            var form = new NameValueCollection();
            var querystring = new NameValueCollection();
            var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
            var user = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("testuser"), new string[] { "Administrator" });

            request.Expect(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
            request.Expect(r => r.Form).Returns(form);
            request.Expect(q => q.QueryString).Returns(querystring);

            response.Expect(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);

            context.Expect(u => u.User).Returns(user);



            return context.Object;
        }

        public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext(string url)
        {
            HttpContextBase context = FakeHttpContext();
            context.Request.SetupRequestUrl(url);

            return context;

        }


        public static void SetFakeControllerContext(this Controller controller)
        {
            var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();
            ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), controller);
            controller.ControllerContext = context;
        }

        public static void SetFakeControllerContext(this Controller controller, RouteData routeData)
        {
            SetFakeControllerContext(controller, new Dictionary<string, string>(), new HttpCookieCollection(), routeData);
        }

        public static void SetFakeControllerContext(this Controller controller, HttpCookieCollection requestCookies)
        {
            SetFakeControllerContext(controller,new Dictionary<string,string>(),requestCookies, new RouteData());
        }

        public static void SetFakeControllerContext(this Controller controller, Dictionary<string, string> formValues)
        {
            SetFakeControllerContext(controller, formValues, new HttpCookieCollection(), new RouteData());
        }

        public static void SetFakeControllerContext(this Controller controller,
            Dictionary<string, string> formValues,
            HttpCookieCollection requestCookies,
            RouteData routeData)
        {
            var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();

            foreach (string key in formValues.Keys)
            {
                httpContext.Request.Form.Add(key, formValues[key]);

            }
            foreach (string key in requestCookies.Keys)
            {
                httpContext.Request.Cookies.Add(requestCookies[key]);

            }
            ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), controller);
            controller.ControllerContext = context;
        }

        public static void SetFakeControllerContextWithLogin(this Controller controller, string userName,
            string password,
            string returnUrl)
        {

            var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();


            httpContext.Request.Form.Add("username", userName);
            httpContext.Request.Form.Add("password", password);
            httpContext.Request.QueryString.Add("ReturnUrl", returnUrl);

            ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), controller);
            controller.ControllerContext = context;
        }


        static string GetUrlFileName(string url)
        {
            if (url.Contains("?"))
                return url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?"));
            else
                return url;
        }

        static NameValueCollection GetQueryStringParameters(string url)
        {
            if (url.Contains("?"))
            {
                NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

                string[] parts = url.Split("?".ToCharArray());
                string[] keys = parts[1].Split("&".ToCharArray());

                foreach (string key in keys)
                {
                    string[] part = key.Split("=".ToCharArray());
                    parameters.Add(part[0], part[1]);
                }

                return parameters;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void SetHttpMethodResult(this HttpRequestBase request, string httpMethod)
        {
            Mock.Get(request)
                .Expect(req => req.HttpMethod)
                .Returns(httpMethod);
        }

        public static void SetupRequestUrl(this HttpRequestBase request, string url)
        {
            if (url == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("url");

            if (!url.StartsWith("~/"))
                throw new ArgumentException("Sorry, we expect a virtual url starting with \"~/\".");

            var mock = Mock.Get(request);

            mock.Expect(req => req.QueryString)
                .Returns(GetQueryStringParameters(url));
            mock.Expect(req => req.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)
                .Returns(GetUrlFileName(url));
            mock.Expect(req => req.PathInfo)
                .Returns(string.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: But he provided an answer, too.

Answer (score 3):

*[Dislaimer: I work at [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com)]*

I know it's not what you've asked but looking at the answers above I have to show another way to do what you need - using [Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product/):

```
var fakeId = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IIdentity>();
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeId.AuthenticationType).WillReturn("Windows");
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeId.Name).WillReturn("TEST_USER");
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeId.IsAuthenticated).WillReturn(true);

var fakePrincipal = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IPrincipal>();
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakePrincipal.Identity).WillReturn(fakeId);

var fakeContext = Isolate.Fake.Instance<HttpContext>();
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeContext.User).WillReturn(fakePrincipal);
```