# Unit testing an MVC action method with a Cache dependency?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, dependency-injection, mocking

I’m relatively new to testing and MVC and came across a sticking point today.  I’m attempting to test an action method that has a dependency on HttpContext.Current.Cache and wanted to know the best practice for achieving the “low coupling” to allow for easy testing.  Here's what I've got so far...

```
 public class CacheHandler : ICacheHandler
 {
    public IList<Section3ListItem> StateList
    {
        get { return (List<Section3ListItem>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["StateList"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Cache["StateList"] = value; }
    }
 ...
```

I then access it like such... I'm using Castle for my IoC.

```
public class ProfileController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISection3Repository _repository;
    private readonly ICacheHandler _cache;

    public ProfileController(ISection3Repository repository, ICacheHandler cacheHandler)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _cache = cacheHandler;
    }

    [UserIdFilter]
    public ActionResult PersonalInfo(Guid userId)
    {
        if (_cache.StateList == null)
            _cache.StateList = _repository.GetLookupValues((int)ELookupKey.States).ToList();
   ...
```

Then in my unit tests I am able to mock up ICacheHandler.

**Would this be considered a 'best practice' and does anyone have any suggestions for other approaches?**

Comment: I would question who should be in charge of checking the cache.  Is the controller really the best place?  All it wants is a StateList.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is to stub [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx). Its documentation states

> When you perform unit testing, you
>   typically use a derived class to
>   implement members with customized
>   behavior that fulfills the scenario
>   you are testing.

This is mostly covered for TypeMock [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677801/mocking-and-httpcontextbase-get-user/678189#678189).

```
var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
httpContext.Stub(x=>x.Cache).Return(yourFakeCacheHere);

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext, ....);

var controller = new HomeController();
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding a specific, **hard-to-test API** (HttpContext.Current) behind and interface and using **Constructor Injection** to inject the dependency into the consumer. That's more or less **textbook DI** (I would add Guard Clauses in the constructor, though).

If you create a new ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio, you will see that in the AccountController.cs file, a very similar thing is being done to hide the MembershipProvider.