# Mocking Querystring-RhinoMocks-MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have  a situation to Mock Querystring.
Does anyone mocked Querystring with RhinoMocks, if so please let me know. I am using MVC 3.

Thank you

Comment: In depends on how you handle query string in your controller. Would you post your controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677801/mocking-and-httpcontextbase-get-user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution based on http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.com/2008/12/mocking-querystring-collection-in.html but using RhinoMocks

```
HttpContextBase httpContextBase;     
HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase;
ControllerBase controllerBase;

controllerBase = mockRepository.DynamicMock<ControllerBase>();

NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("KEY", "VALUE");

httpRequestBase  =  mockRepository.DynamicMock<HttpRequestBase>();
Expect.Call(httpRequestBase.QueryString).Return(nvc);

httpContextBase = mockRepository.DynamicMock<HttpContextBase>();
Expect.Call(httpContextBase.Request).Return(httpRequestBase);

var context = new ControllerContext(httpContextBase, new RouteData(), controllerBase);

yourController.ControllerContext = context;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you asked for RhinoMocks, I found this solution and adapted it for Moq. So for anyone else who's interested, here's the Moq version of @TomAx's answer:

```
        NameValueCollection queryString = new NameValueCollection();
        queryString.Add("KEY", "VALUE");

        // Set up a request
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        request.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryString);

        // Inject into the controller
        var controllerBase = new Mock<ControllerBase>();
        var contextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        contextBase.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

        request.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryString);
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextBase.Object, new RouteData(), controllerBase.Object);
        var controller = new YourController();
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

Comment: There has to be a shorter way,.

Comment: @ByteBlast if you find a shorter way, please post it here.

Comment: Based on your answer (thanks) and a few others, I came up with this helper whose body is marginally shorter: https://gist.github.com/ByteBlast/8fbbb425bc60f582780e