# How to populate a Chart ( Using System.Web.Helpers.Chart ) in LinqPad?

Tags: linqpad

I have the code below, run it in LinqPad 4.40.03 + Sql Server 2008 R2 + NorthWind.

LinqPad return exception: "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: httpContext".

Please give me the Final Fixed code, I want it populate a chart ( Using System.Web.Helpers.Chart ) in linqpad output screen.

```
void Main()
{
    var q = from p in Products
            let s = p.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.Quantity) * p.UnitPrice
            orderby s
            select new { ProductName = p.ProductName, Sales = s};

    var basicChart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Product Sales")
        .DataBindTable(dataSource: q, xField: "ProductName")
        .Write();

    basicChart.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ASP.NET charting control relies on HttpContext.Current which is present only when running an ASP.NET application.

You could try [mocking an HttpContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677886/46223), or else use the charting control in `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` instead:

```
var q = from p in Products
    let s = p.OrderDetails.Sum(o => o.Quantity) * p.UnitPrice
    orderby s
    select new { ProductName = p.ProductName, Sales = s};

var chart = new Chart();

var ca = new ChartArea();
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
chart.ChartAreas.Add (ca);

var series = new Series { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar};
series.Points.DataBind (q.Take(20), "ProductName", "Sales", null);
chart.Series.Add (series);
chart.Dump ("Chart");
```

Comment: Thanks Great Joe! The chart is beautiful populated. LinqPad is amazing powerful.

Comment: Hi Joe, I mock an HttpContext(using Moq), then took a lot time tried to populate the chat in LinqPad Using System.Web.Helpers.Chart, but still can not make it work. Can you please give me the final code like above, Thanks!